# Get variable out of a multiple nested functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm trying to get a variable **(lib)** out of a multiple nested functions.

```
var nme='name',lib;

$('script').each(function(){

    var src=$(this).attr('src');

    if(typeof(src)==='undefined'){src='';}

if(src.indexOf(nme)!==-1){

    $.get($(this).attr('src').match(/\w([^ ]+)spbin/)[0]+'/conf/ptmedia.plist',
        function(c){
            $(c).find('key').each(function(){
                if($(this).html()==='MediaLib'){lib=$(this).next().html();}
            });
        }
    );

}
});

if(lib==='some lib'){DO STUFF}
```

Comment: Ajax is **asynchronous**! Move `$('.null').html(lib);` into the success callback. More information here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/218196.

Comment: Why can't you just... Wait what's wrong?: This should work fine.

Comment: Are you really trying to load scripts via ajax to look up something in their source code? Then you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem as follows:

```
var nme='name';

    $('script').each(function(){

    var src=$(this).attr('src');

        if(typeof(src)==='undefined'){src='';}

        if(src.indexOf(nme)!==-1){media=$(this).attr('src').match(/\w([^ ]+)spbin/)[0];}

    });


    function ffn(){
    $($.ajax({url:media+'/conf/ptmedia.plist',async:false}).responseText).find('key').each(function(){
        if($(this).html()==='string'){value=$(this).next().html();}
    });

    return value;
    }

    if(ffn()==='some lib'){DO STUFF}
```

Thank you all for your participation and good ideas!

Comment: Hi, using synchronous AJAX is usually a bad solution. It blocks the browser until it arrives (meaning for example, the window can be unresponsive (stuck) for 10 seconds) and it is generally not practical. I would reconsider.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Hi! Thank you for your comment! Perhaps you could offer another solution?

Comment: I did :) In my answer, also, it turns out this question is a duplicate of another one, you might want to also check the answers there

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I do not think it is a duplicate, because the problem here Neuve AJAX, but how to make the variable of nested functions. While I do not see a way out. Maybe you can help me in solving this problem

Comment: The scope was never a problem, it was syncronization. See my answer

Answer (score 4):

Your problem isn't with scoping, the problem is that you have an AJAX call which is asynchronous. 
You should put the change of HTML in `.null` inside the callback function instead:

```
$.get($(this).attr('src').match(/\w([^ ]+)spbin/)[0]+'/conf/ptmedia.plist',
        function(c){
            $(c).find('key').each(function(){
                if($(this).html()==='MediaLib'){lib=$(this).next().html();}

                $('.null').html(lib);
            });
        }
});
```

In JavaScript often IO is *asynchronous*. This means that when you make an AJAX call it does not happen immidiately but rather waits for the value to return from the HTTP request and then calls a *callback*. In your case that `function(c)` is the callback, it gets executed when *the value of the AJAX call arrived*.

So in fact you were updating the `HTML` content of `.null` to undefined, since it got the value of `lib` before it was updated.

Comment: +1 but you should explain what this means

Comment: It works, but i need get this variable in another place

Comment: @Aleksov in that case you need to make sure the callback happened by then. JavaScript runs (usually, there are ways around this) in a _single thread_, every iteration it checks all the events that happen (like an AJAX returned value) and runs code based on them. If you need your lib variable available it _MUST_ be in that callback. If you feel like you're getting messy code you can move it into a method.

Comment: @Aleksov: As long as the other code is run after the response is received, everything is fine. You just have to make sure that it does.

Comment: I once solved this very same issue on SO (for somebody else), but did totally mess up on explaining why it happened. This explanation is great, wish I could give you +5.

Comment: To down-voter, care to explain what I can improve with this answer, and which parts you did not like?